# Take trip time of cars in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I need to count ticks each car takes from start of trip till end of trip. I am working on showing road bloackade simulation in netlogo. For this trip time of cars is needed to be calculated.

For this I have made following code:

```
to-report start-journey-time  
  report  min-pxcor
  end
 to-report end-journey-time    
  report max-pxcor

end
```

Answer (score 1):

The current value of the tick counter is access with the reporter `ticks`. Note that this is different from `tick`, which is used to increment the counter.

So, assuming each car has a variable called journey-time, you can do something like this. When the journey starts: `set journey-time ticks`, and when the journey finishes `set journey-time ticks - journey-time`. This is not great code since you are using the same variable for both the start time and the duration, but it saves a variable. If you want more readable code, use separate variables.

Comment: This is doing same. The graph output is same. Another solution?

Comment: This is a solution to your question - it calculates journey time. If it's not solving your problem, then you need to actually describe the problem. How are you using the reporters? Show the procedure that calls them. How is the minimum and maximum `pxcor` supposed to measure time?

Comment: If you inspect one of the cars,  what do you see?  Is journey-time always zero?